# Scifi movie about a spaceship where alien creatures (birds) become smaller as they come closer, ie., reverse-perspective?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, spaceship

Have been looking everywhere for the name of this movie. Here's what I remember:

A spaceship and crew are flying somewhere. Something goes wrong and 2 people from the crew have to go outside in suits to fix it. While outside, one guy somehow ends up floating away from the ship for a good amount of time before he is rescued. When he wakes up inside he has apparently gone insane and keeps talking about 'the birds'. He says the birds are inside him, the tiny birds, or something along those lines. Turns out he's right and that while he was outside, alien creatures entered his body and have now entered the ship through him. Interesting thing about these creatures is that they work on reverse-perspective, ie., they are larger when they are far away from you and become smaller and smaller and eventually microscopic as they come closer to you. As far as I remember, the movie ends with the crew fighting these 'birds' that cant be seen close up but are HUGE at relatively large distances.

Please help if you know what I am talking about. Have done all kinds of searches and failed.

Comment: Not sure how that is reverse-perspective. Most objects are smaller when they are further away. So you might want to edit your title

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you. Editing now.

Comment: https://youtu.be/GFTgkibl7DU?t=30s

Comment: @Richard Hah! Well, the creators of this movie did not understand that distinction.

Comment: I am looking for the same title. I know it as a short story, not a movie. I can't find it anywhere and I would like to find this short story...

Comment: What those alien birds looked like?